# How to populate android ListView Dyanamically

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a program that displays list of items(diseases), the way I designed is to show Image displayed on the left followed by a text. What I want to do is to populate the images and text of Array called "diseases" dynamically, I managed to do populate the array but would like help how to populate with the image with the text. I would like to helped how to setup an array for images to do like the disease array. thank you

custom_row.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/diabetesImage"
    android:src="@drawable/diabetes"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/diseaseTextView"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

Main file : HealthActivity.java

```
    public class HealthActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_health);

    String [] diseases = {"HIV","Tuberclosis","Diabetes",
            "Blood Pressure","Liver disease", "Malaria"};

    ListAdapter diseaseAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, diseases);
    ListView TopicListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TopicList);
    TopicListView.setAdapter(diseaseAdapter);
    TopicListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String disease = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position)) ;
                    Toast.makeText(HealthActivity.this, disease, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                }
            }
    );

}
```

}

help class: CustomAdapter.java

```
    class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


CustomAdapter(Context context, String [] diseases) {
    super(context,R.layout.custom_row, diseases);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater diseaseInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = diseaseInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

    String singleDiseaseText = getItem(position);
    TextView diseaseTextView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.diseaseTextView);
    ImageView diseaseImageView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.diabetesImage);



    diseaseTextView.setText(singleDiseaseText);
    diseaseImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.diabetes);

    return customView;


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Go through this [Android Custom ListView with Images and Text](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html) tutorial you will be able to create and understand what you are seeking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should path your custom arraylist to your adappter and assign the value of your text in the custom object to your textview and I think you should use lazy loadding for loadding your images and I recommend you to use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Answer (score 0):

I'll not specify in depth because this is not a big thing to do, if you know the fundamentals right.

1. Define your listview.
2. Define your data-set , which is to be shown in this list's list_item
    If data is coming from a server u'll have to use Async Tasks and get it in xml or json form and parse it in a jsonObject OR JsonArray
3. You'll have crate an adapter a Base Adapter will be a good option,which will take data from your data-set index-wise and fill it inside the view and attach that view to the list.
4. Finally set that adapter to the list.

There are plenty of examples on youtube follow them, you'll be good to go.